# Settings publication to Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the best practice of configuration management for web applications that are published to Amazon Beanstalk?

Now configuration of our web application is separated among several files. One of them is web.config, where we have basic connection strings.
Others are custom xml files with configuration of different application modules. These files are mapped to config classes via default xml serialization.

The simplest way is to add these configs into Visual Studio's project. But this solution produces several questions:

1. We do not want our production settings be visible to newcome team members.
2. We want to be able to switch between different configurations of application - we have our local server with SQL Server, which is used for development as it is faster and more responsive than Amazon's instances we use.

We can consider moving all application and its modules settings into `System.Configuration` format and use config file transformations, having two solution build configurations - one for Amazon and one for dev environment. But this means we would have not to forget to switch to Amazon solution configuration before publishing project. Is it possible to set solution configuration that will be used to publish to Amazon by default?